# Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid. While getting Access Token From Azure

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to Get access token from Azure AD. For that I have performed below Steps

1) Created an Enterprise application on Azure Active Directory

[image]

2) I am able to get the Access token using Authorisation --->> 'Get New Access token'

[image]

3) Hit the 'POST' request for `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Application ID>/oauth2/token` URL

Have Configured below for POST Body

- Authorization TYPE is OAuth 2.0
- Passed the Body using 'form-data' as below
  [image]

ClientID is ApplicationID from Application created at 1st step

Code is Also ApplicationID from Application created at 1st step

Not sure if I have configured it correctly

4) Using Same access code when I try to send an Request I am getting below error response

```
`{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: 60b8fb68-40d5-43da-9b7b-36de021c2900\r\nCorrelation ID: 90ed2f2c-1ac8-4044-8742-493a3fce51be\r\nTimestamp: 2019-07-03 12:42:32Z",
    "error_codes": [
        9002313
    ],
    "timestamp": "2019-07-03 12:42:32Z",
    "trace_id": "60b8fb68-40d5-43da-9b7b-36de021c2900",
    "correlation_id": "90ed2f2c-1ac8-4044-8742-493a3fce51be"
}
```

[image]

Please let me know where I am wrong or something needs to be changed.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that the code returned after authorization in the redirect URI is actually something like `www.yourredirecturl.com/?code=....&section_state=....`

So copy the whole thing after `?code=`; include the `&section_state` and make the `code` incorrect.

Comment: let code=location.search.split('code=')[1];  code=code.split('&')[0]; //add this

Answer (score 5):

If I am not wrong you are trying to get get token using [`OAuth 2.0 code grant flow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code).

For this code flow there are two steps:

1. Request an authorization code
2. With this authorization code need request token

**Get authorization code**

You paste following code either in browser or post man. In postman do it like below:

[image]

> ```
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTennatId.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YourClentId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read
> ```

Once you got the authorization code , copy it for next step.

**Use the authorization code to request an access token:**

```
Token Request Endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantId/oauth2/token

client_id:YourClientId
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All
redirect_uri:https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:YourAppsSecret
code:Paste Your Code Here
```

**Post Man Format:**

[image]

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Do I need active subscriptions in azure while making making above call for authorization code ? I am doing this proof of concept before actual implementation in my code. ??

Comment: Yeah you need that. In that case may not get token.