# AAD Outh Generate token failure AADSTS50076

Tags: azure-active-directory

my code to generate outhtoken from AAD suddenly started failing with messsage "AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access {resourceid}".  with error code 50076.

I have not change my location and same was working earlier. I am not aware if AAD admin has done any changes, after which it started failing. in azure portal it shows that app has admin consent granted for the resource.

Any suggestion/how to troubleshoot and fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The error usually occurs if you are trying to fetch access token
> using ROPC flow for **MFA enabled user**.

I have one user where MFA is enabled like below:

[image]

When I tried to generate access token using ROPC flow for this MFA enabled user, I got **same error** like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token
grant_type:password
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
resource: https://graph.microsoft.com
username: user1@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password: xxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To resolve the error, you have to either **disable MFA** for that user
> or change your authentication flow to **authorization code**.

To generate access token using authorization code flow, run below **authorization request** in browser:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=appID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

When I ran above authorization in browser and tried to authenticate with MFA enabled user, it asked for **MFA** like below:

[image]

After completing the MFA, I got **`code`** value in address bar successfully like below:

[image]

Now, I am able to generate access token successfully using **authorization code flow** for MFA enabled user via Postman with below parameters:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
code:<paste_code_from_above_step>
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for details. in AAD it is showing MFA as disabled for the user. When i tried the Authzoriation code flow as you have mentioned. I got code but when trying to get access token in postman, it failed with message  "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request.

Comment: @user9297554 Please check how you're passing parameters to get access token. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870805/invalid-request-request-is-malformed-or-invalid-while-getting-access-token-fro).